# Create Javascript Library only for less re-writing purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I create a simple javascript library only for the purpose of not writing the function all the time?

For example, for Jquery's ajax, I'd have to use the following:

```
$.ajax({ url: xxx,
         type: xxx,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: xxx,
         success : function(data){
         }
       })
```

I want to be able to do something like getajax(url, type, success function) or postajax(url, type, data, success function)

Is this possible? I'm currently having two three issue
1. Creating library seems to be alot of work? (I'm pretty new, can't I just pack them together and put it in .js and import it?)
2. How do I pass the function that jquery ajax does on success?
3. Can I include library within library?

Thanks alot, I'm new to Javascript and there's alot of similar websites needs to be completed based on the same format.

Peter

Comment: Jquery $.post() and $.get() do this.

Comment: Yeah you right this is alot of work to make it work on different browsers and so on

Comment: The jquery Ajax is just an example, if there's a function that I'm going to use alot of times, can I pack it in a library and just import that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just want to come back and answer my own question, since I didn't get the help that I was looking for before. Using the jQuery post and get Ajax function, it won't handle error. So simply create another .js file, and add the following and include it in your html.

```
function getAjax(PageName, Action, Variables, dofunction) {

    $.ajax({
            url : PageName+'/'+Action+'?'+Variables,
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            success : dofunction,        
            error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    errLogin(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                }
    });

}
```

function postAjax(PageName, Action, Variables, Data, dofunction) {

```
    $.ajax({
            url : PageName+'/'+Action+'?'+Variables,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : Data,
            success : dofunction,        
            error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    errLogin(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment, jQuery provided two method for this already.

```
$.post(URL,data,callback);
$.get(URL,callback);
```

And to answer your second question regarding extending jQuery to have further functions

```
$.extend({
    myPlugin: function (someVar) {
        // do something here, in this case we'll write to the console
        console.log(someVar);
    }
});

$.myPlugin("Some Text");
```